# How to count unique words from a text file after a specific string in every line?

Tags: python, regex, file, count, unique

Python-noob here:

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18918', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '81', 'end': '95', 'Character': 'Will'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19012', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '155', 'end': '158', 'Character': 'Jonathan'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19050', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '239', 'end': '242', 'Character': 'Nancy'} 
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19111', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '845', 'end': '850', 'Character': 'Steve'}
```

etc.

I would like to be able to count the unique characters' names and count each of their occurances. As in: ignore everything in every line until the string **'Character':** and therefore considering only the character's name.

So far I have this code, after trying many other approaches, including RegEx, but without the wanted results (it prints and counts everything):

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import tkFileDialog

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

f = open(filename, "r")

lines = f.readlines()

f.close()


cnt = Counter()

for line in lines:
    cnt[line.split("'Character':", 2)] +=1

print cnt
print sum(cnt.values())
```

An optimal output would be like so:

```
Jonathan: 3
Joyce: 2
Will: 1
Nancy: 1
Steve: 1
```

Any kind of help or hints would be appreciated!

EDIT: The text file above was generated from an .xmi file that has information in a way that is not easily readable. As I mentioned in a comment for one of the answers below: This was my first-try approach to represent wanted combined information visually. I am not sure if there's a better way to represent such data other than in a text file to be able to work with it. Create a new .xmi file for that, maybe?

So, as requested, here's my code that generated the .xmi file to the text file:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:

import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import (Element, ElementTree, SubElement, Comment, tostring)

ET.register_namespace("pos","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/lexmorph/type/pos.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("tcas","http:///uima/tcas.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("xmi","http://www.omg.org/XMI")
ET.register_namespace("cas","http:///uima/cas.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("tweet","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/lexmorph/type/pos/tweet.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("morph","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/lexmorph/type/morph.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("dependency","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/syntax/type/dependency.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type5","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/semantics/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type6","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/syntax/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type2","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/metadata/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type3","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/ner/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type4","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/segmentation/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("type","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/coref/type.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("constituent","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/syntax/type/constituent.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("chunk","http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/syntax/type/chunk.ecore")
ET.register_namespace("custom","http:///webanno/custom.ecore")

def sofa(annotation):
    f = open(annotation)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    node = root.find("{http:///uima/cas.ecore}Sofa") # we remove cas:View
    return node.attrib['sofaString']

path ="valhalla.xmi"
with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as filename:
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'emospan': 'http:///webanno/custom.ecore', 
      'id':'http://www.omg.org/XMI',
      'relspan': 'http:///webanno/custom.ecore',
      'sentence': 'http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/segmentation/type.ecore',
      'annotator': "http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/metadata/type.ecore"}
my_id = '{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id'


top = Element('corpus', encoding="utf-8") 
text = sofa(path).replace("\n"," ")

def stimcount():
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        for rel_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterRelation",ns):
            if rel_node.attrib['Relation']=="Stimulus":
                source = rel_node.attrib['Governor']
                target = rel_node.attrib['Dependent']
                for span_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterEmotion",ns):
                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==source:

                        print(span_node.attrib['Emotion'])

                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==target:
                        print(span_node.attrib)
                        print(span_node.attrib, file=f)
```

Comment: Your text file seems like it's in json format. Which using the json package would probably make it easier to read the key/value pairs then the actual text data.

Comment: @Karl it is not json, as it uses single quotes.

Comment: What you can do is use regex to capture the name, then try adding the name as a key to a dictionary. If it succeeds, set the value to 1. If it fails, find the key with that name and increment the value.

Comment: @nosklo i don't really know json - is this the only difference? Then it should be a matter of simple character replace to then use json or pandas from_json, right?

Comment: @SpghttCd it is the only difference I can see in the example data - but there could be other differences depending on the dicts contents. The correct fix is to generate a json in first place!

Comment: will you be okay with a shell solution, it will be a single command line code but much more efficient ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original text file is very sad, as it seems to contain representations of python dicts written in text format, one per line!

This is a very bad way of generating a text data file. You should change the code that generates this file, to generate another format like csv or json file instead of naively writing string representations to a text file. If you use csv or json, then you have libraries already written and tested to help you parse the contents and extract each element easily.

If you still want that, you can use ast.literal_eval to actually run the code on each line:

```
import ast
import collections
with open(filename) as infile:
     print(collections.Counter(ast.literal_eval(line)['Character'] for line in infile))
```

**EDIT:** Now that you added an example of the file generation, I can suggest you use another format, like json:

```
def stimcount():
    results = []
    for rel_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterRelation",ns):
        if rel_node.attrib['Relation']=="Stimulus":
            source = rel_node.attrib['Governor']
            target = rel_node.attrib['Dependent']
            for span_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterEmotion",ns):
                if span_node.attrib[my_id]==source:

                    print(span_node.attrib['Emotion'])

                if span_node.attrib[my_id]==target:
                    print(span_node.attrib)
                    results.append(span_node.attrib)

    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(results, f)
```

Then your code that reads the data could be as simple as:

```
with open('results.txt') as f:
    results = json.load(f)
r = collections.Counter(d['Character'] for d in results)
for n, (ch, number) in enumerate(r.items()): 
    print('{} - {}, {}'.format(n, ch, number))
```

Another option is to use csv format. It allows you to specify a list of interesting columns and ignore the rest:

```
def stimcount():
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        cf = csv.DictWriter(f, ['begin', 'end', 'Character'], extrasaction='ignore')
        cf.writeheader()
        for rel_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterRelation",ns):
            if rel_node.attrib['Relation']=="Stimulus":
                source = rel_node.attrib['Governor']
                target = rel_node.attrib['Dependent']
                for span_node in root.findall("emospan:CharacterEmotion",ns):
                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==source:

                        print(span_node.attrib['Emotion'])

                    if span_node.attrib[my_id]==target:
                        print(span_node.attrib)
                        cf.writerow(span_node.attrib)
```

Then to read it easily:

```
with open('results.txt') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    r = collections.Counter(d['Character'] for d in cf)
    for n, (ch, number) in enumerate(r.items()): 
        print('{} - {}, {}'.format(n, ch, number))
```

Comment: I created this text file from an .xmi file. This was a first-try approach to represent some combined desired data that is usually scattered in order for me to have at least a visual representation of the results I'm seeking.

Comment: @Waldkamel if you can show your code for generating the text file, we can provide a way to generate it in universal json or csv format instead, then you can more reliably and easily read it in any language you want

Comment: I added it now in the question section. I included only one function as an example; there are others with similar form.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me the most :)

Comment: so far it counts the occurrences of each unique character. Is there a way to make it count the different unique characters as items as well?
e.g.
#, character, occurences |
1 ,'Jonathan', 20 |
2, 'Joyce', 14 |
3, 'Will', 5 |

I tried sum().values() but it just sums up the total number of occurrences.

Comment: @Waldkamel I don't understand the question? What are you getting as result of the code above? Maybe ask another question with updated code?

Comment: Let me rephrase: how can I enumerate the results of the Counter() as used by you ? I would like to be able to print the number of items (here: Characters) and know that there are e.g. 5 different characters with so and so occurrences.

Comment: @Waldkamel Oh so just text output formatting? `for n, (ch, number) in enumerate(result.items()): print('{} - {}, {}'.format(n, ch, number)` added to the answer

Comment: Perfect! Thanks once again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Regex solution:

```
file_stuff = """{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18918', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '81', 'end': '95', 'Character': 'Will'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19012', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '155', 'end': '158', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19050', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '239', 'end': '242', 'Character': 'Nancy'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19111', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '845', 'end': '850', 'Character': 'Steve'}"""

import re
from collections import Counter

r = re.compile("(?<=\'Character\'\:\s\')\w+(?=\')")
# EDIT: use "(?<=\'Character\'\:\s\')(.+)(?=\')" to match names with quotes...
# or other characters, as pointed out in comments.
print(Counter(r.findall(file_stuff)))
# Counter({'Jonathan': 3, 'Joyce': 2, 'Will': 1, 'Nancy': 1, 'Steve': 1})
```

Comment: Will fail if a character name contains a quote in it

Comment: @nosklo That's correct! My guess is we could replace `\w+` for `(.+)`, I'll edit the answer, thank you.

Comment: Nice and short. But shouldn't it be possible to additionally detect names containing all characters except '? E.g. C3PO, E.T. or T1000

Answer (score 0):

Using `ast` and `collections` modules

**Ex:**

```
import ast
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        val = ast.literal_eval(line)
        d[val["Character"]] += 1
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Will': 1, 'Steve': 1, 'Jonathan': 3, 'Nancy': 1, 'Joyce': 2})
```

Comment: It worked for a bit and then I started getting this error message everytime I run the code:
"val = ast.literal_eval(line)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
return _convert(nodoe_or_string)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string"

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can have a `pandas` solution, too...:

```
txt = """{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18836', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '27', 'end': '30', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18828', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '31', 'end': '37', 'Character': 'Joyce'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '18918', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '81', 'end': '95', 'Character': 'Will'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19012', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '155', 'end': '158', 'Character': 'Jonathan'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19050', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '239', 'end': '242', 'Character': 'Nancy'}
{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id': '19111', 'sofa': '12', 'begin': '845', 'end': '850', 'Character': 'Steve'}"""

import pandas as pd

# replace the StringIO-stuff by your file-path
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="'Character': '", header=None, usecols=[1])
            1
0  Jonathan'}
1  Jonathan'}
2     Joyce'}
3     Joyce'}
4      Will'}
5  Jonathan'}
6     Nancy'}
7     Steve'}

df = df[1].str.split('\'', expand=True)
          0  1
0  Jonathan  }
1  Jonathan  }
2     Joyce  }
3     Joyce  }
4      Will  }
5  Jonathan  }
6     Nancy  }
7     Steve  }

df.groupby(0).count()
          1
0          
Jonathan  3
Joyce     2
Nancy     1
Steve     1
Will      1
```

The idea is to read the file as two columns `sep`arated by `'Character': '` and import only the second (`usecols`).
Then `split` again at `'`.
The rest is ordinary `groupby` / `count`